# Python 3: Attribute error: Object is not callable

Tags: python

I am trying to run a model for prediction using Python 3. Here are the lines of code.

```
try:    
    with open("SalePriceModel_3.pkl","rb") as fp :
        loadedModel = pickle.load(fp,encoding="latin-1")
        sys.stdout.write('2')


    xCols = [u'MSSubClass', u'LotArea', u'OverallQual', u'OverallCond', u'YearBuilt',....]


    listVals = list()

    for colName in xCols :
        if colName in inData.keys():
            listVals.append(inData[colName])
        else:
            listVals.append(0)


    salePrice = loadedModel.predict(np.array(listVals).reshape(-1,33))


    return jsonify({'PredictedSalesPrice': salePrice[0]})
except Exception as  e:
    print(e)
    return e;
```

Could someone guide how to get over this issue?

Here is the full error message include traceback:

```
2'NoneType' object has no attribute 'keys'
[2018-07-21 22:23:23,394] ERROR in app: Exception on /api/getSalesPrice [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\anant\Documents\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\anant\Documents\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1615, in full_dispatch_request
    return self.finalize_request(rv)
  File "C:\Users\anant\Documents\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1630, in finalize_request
    response = self.make_response(rv)
  File "C:\Users\anant\Documents\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1740, in make_response
    rv = self.response_class.force_type(rv, request.environ)
  File "C:\Users\anant\Documents\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\wrappers.py", line 921, in force_type
    response = BaseResponse(*_run_wsgi_app(response, environ))
  File "C:\Users\anant\Documents\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\test.py", line 923, in run_wsgi_app
    app_rv = app(environ, start_response)
TypeError: 'AttributeError' object is not callable
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Jul/2018 22:23:23] "GET /api/getSal
```

Comment: Are you sure it's this line of code that's giving you problems? Because it's inside a `try`, if something wrong happened there, it should go to your `except` statement instead of throwing an error.

Comment: I have edited the question to add more lines; Yes the try statement does have an except statement. The program upon running throws error as mentioned with my question.

Comment: Show the complete error message you're getting, including the traceback.

Comment: You might want to use the `traceback` module to get the full traceback of your exception. or just remove the `try`/`except` block so that the exception goes uncaught so you can see the traceback when it gets printed out by default.

Comment: @AnanthSubramanian: Edit the question to add the traceback (as a code block, so the formatting doesn't get messed up).

Comment: The complete error message has been added to the question.

Comment: That exception does not appear to have anything to do with the code you've shown. It appears to be a flask issue, rather than a calculation issue of any sort. Perhaps you should show where your flask app is defined? You may also want to add appropriate tags to the question.

Comment: Here is how the app is defined:
@app.route('/api/getSalesPrice', methods=['GET','POST'])
## This function loads a saved model and predicts house price on the incoming data. 
def predictSalePrice() :

 inData = request.json
 salePrice = 0
The above lines of code precede the try statement.